# Root Android tablet with adequate SuperUser app

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, root-access

I'm an Android developer doing a project which requires rooting the device and doing some `su` task to fulfill the needs. The problem is that all the rooting software solutions that worked for me (iRoot, Kingoroot, Kingroot) have inadequate SuperUser app that brought TONS of additional malware stuff such as unintended lock screens, ads etc. Also, when my app does some `su` command the SuperUser app won't let it do it unless user accepts root permission in the dialog. I can't accept that - the app is running in kiosk mode on devices located in stores. I think there are two ways:

1. Please provide some rooting programm which has normal SuperUser app that won't do shady stuff and ask for root permission all the time (at first launch it would be ok, or set in the settings).
2. Or the rooting solution which won't install its own SuperUser app. I assume there are some decent SuperUser apps on the market that will allow my app do well.

The target devices run Android 4.4.2 version. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me ask this: you want your app to be able to call `su` and obtain root permissions without needing an user to act. Correct?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman yes

Comment: Are you able to flash a custom recovery on those devices?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman yes, initially the one who will be installing the device will flash it, install pure system image and root the device

Comment: Well, if you can flash TWRP, then you might create your own flashable ZIP based on [this](http://download.clockworkmod.com/superuser/superuser.zip) one made by ClockWorkMod, and flash it. In order to grant root permissions automatically (bad for security), you just need to place the **su** file inside **/system/xbin**, `chown 0.2000` and `chmod 755`. Then, create a symlink to that file inside **/system/bin**, call it **su** and `chown 0.2000`, `chmod 755`.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks for your advice. That's a pity, but I don't think the guy who will be installing the device is a specialist in such thing. He won't handle what you propose.

Comment: I see. Well, you might try to flash the same ZIP I provided above (which also installs the root manager [SuperUser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser)). After you've confirmed that root is working, just uninstall the abovementioned root manager manually. You'll retain the **su** binary and have unlimited access to it, plus this method would be easier for your collaborator to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do so is to Root your device with kingroot, then replace it with SuperSU.

Here is a detailed guide provided by MrW0lf : [How to Remove/Replace Kingroot/KingUser with SuperSU](http://www.w0lfdroid.com/2015/05/How-to-Remove-Replace-KingUser-KingRoot-with-SuperSU.html)